# Hide content of <h2> when certain text appears - JQuery

Tags: jquery, text

On the face of it, this should be easy but I have stumbled on it for some time already.

I am trying to hide a `<h2>` only tag when certain text appears. CMS generates the tag. HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="BrandContent">
  <h2>All Brands</h2>
  <div class="BlockContent">
     BRANDS LISTED HERE...
  </div>
</div>
```

If "All Brands" is included in the h2 tag, then I want the tag removed or hidden.

I have tried a few combinations of the below code without success:

```
if($('#BrandContent > div.h2:contains("All Brands")').length > 0) {
    $('#BrandContent h2').css('visibility', 'hidden')
}
```

and

```
 $('#BrandContent h2').remove(":contains('All Brands')");
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.
M

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the help! It now works although it first appears during page load, then disappears as the page completes loading. If I hide the element with CSS, and I make it appear with Jquery, what is the opposite of ":contains"? That is I will make it visible if it does not contain "All Brands". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this selector

```
$('#BrandContent > h2:contains("All Brands")').css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3D5ce/21/)**

**You were using the id Attribute but using the class selector**

```
id="BrandContent">
```

**Your first try** had a small mistake

```
$('#BrandContent > div.h2
```

You were looking for a `div` which has class `.h2` which is not present in your `HTML`

Comment: @user2469528.. Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: Is there a way to make it not be visible when the page loads. Right now it appears, then disappears. Can this be done via CSS? Thanks!!

Comment: `:contains` is not a CSS selector.. And there is no `CSS` selector that can be used to select a element on a condition based on its content

Comment: Hi @Susahanth, so if I make it hidden in CSS, how do I make it visible if it does not contains "All Brands"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrorg -

it should be like this -

```
$('#BrandContent > h2:contains("All Brands")')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#BrandContent > h2:contains("All Brands"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use wrong selector because "BrandContent" is id and you are useing as class. so it should be like as follow:

```
$('#BrandContent > h2:contains("All Brands")').hide();
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CtGCs/)